# How to reset Print Spooler

Tags: printer, printing, crash, print-spooler

I believe my problems started when I installed a printer with an incorrect driver.

Now I have a broken Print Spooler and I cannot interact with anything that has to do with printing.

I have to go to "Computer Management -> services -> Print Spooler -> start service" to even see the printers under "Devices and Printers".

I can see this window:
[image]

Taking any action on any printer causes the spool to crash.

What are my options?

is there anything like cleanspl.exe for XP that I can use on this Windows 7 machine?
or is there a better solution?

Comment: Maybe the answer provided [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-printer-spooler-stopped-and-cant-print/39804f30-127f-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) can be of any help to you?

Comment: Just found the same solution here: http://superuser.com/questions/370511/print-spooler-starts-and-automatically-stops-when-add-printer-clicked?rq=1

Comment: Check out this very thorough guide: http://members.shaw.ca/bsanders/CleanPrinterDrivers.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if the problem is as you described, then you can manually install another driver for the device.

1. Go into `Computer Management` and then `Devices`.
2. Locate the printer you installed the driver for, right click it
3. Select `Update Driver`
4. Manually select the right driver file by choosing to do so from the disk.

Now, if that problem really were the root of your issues this should solve it. As per [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/print-spooler-keeps-crashing-in-windows-7-ultimate/f47b10d6-fba4-412e-bf49-5daaba31c601), they suggest removing all your printers and starting from scratch.

Also suggested there, you can try clearing the printing sub system.

1. In Explorer, rename everything in this folder (or delete it)
   `c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86`
2. Go into the registry by typing `REGEDIT` into the run dialog box
3. Navigate to the following key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environment\Windows NT x86`
4. In this key, there should be two subkeys
   `Drivers`
   `Print Processors`
5. If there are any other subkeys, export them (in case this causes you problems) and then delete them.
6. Navigate to the following key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors`
7. In this key, there should be 7 subkeys
   `BJ Language Monitor

   Local Port

   Microsoft Document Imaging Writer Monitor

   Microsoft Shared Fax Monitor

   Standard TCP/IP Port

   USB Monitor

   WSD Port`
8. If there are any extra keys, export them and delete them.
9. Reconnect to any printers, taking care to install the proper drivers